# How to avoid function to die to 'Couldn't resolve host name' in R?

Tags: r

in my package, there is a function calling a https-address.

I am checking with `curl::has_internet()` for an internet connection and with `httr::http_error()` for http-errors.

My problem is:

if this function gets an invalid URL, like https://foobarfoo.bar, the function dies with `'Couldn't resolve host name'`

My question is:

is there a way to keep the function alive, throwing "NA" or something instead of dying?
E.g. is there a way to "safely" test for the host name before executing my function?

Comment: `tryCatch` could be useful

Comment: tryCatch does not avoid the function to die .. :/

Comment: even `tryCatch(curl::nslookup("foobardodod.fd"))` dies with an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tryCatch` function with the `error` argument to solve this issue:

```r
tryCatch(curl::nslookup("foobardodod.fd"), error = function(e) NA)
```

returns

```r
#> NA
```

as defined in `error`, if `curl::nslookup("foobardodod.fd")` fails.